# How can I disable the MOTD when using Git over SSH on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, git

I'm using Git on Windows, with a repository over SSH.
Whenever I carry out any action I get the MOTD from the server (which is a legal warning from the company I work for).

It looks like if I was on Linux I could disable this with a .hushlogin file, but I've tried placing that in both the Home folder (Actually f:\ in my case) and in c:\users\$myID, and it didn't work in either case.

What's the correct method for handling this?

(It's using ssh.exe from the Git\bin install folder, if that makes a difference)

Comment: The `motd` is only printed for interactive sessions.  Are you sure the `motd` is coming from `ssh` and not from some login script?

Comment: I'm running it from Jenkins kicking off a Powershell script which then calls Git..  It appears whenever Irun a Git Clone, Fetch, or Push, and not when I call anything else.  There's no login script to anything.

Comment: On the git server, the account you are using *could* have a script running at login.  Have you verified that something like `ssh my_git_acct@my_git_server ls` does *not* give you the `motd`?

Comment: "ssh subdomain.domain.com" gives me the motd.  Before asking for a password.

Comment: `ssh` has two modes.  Interactive and non-interactive.  Non-interactive should not give the `motd`.  Presumably, git is using non-interactive.  If you are going to test non-interactive, you need to run a command (eg: `ls`) as suggested previously.  If you `ssh` without a command, as you just suggested, then you should get the `motd`.

Comment: Are you `ssh`ing from your Windows machine (with `Git\bin\ssh.exe`) **to** a remote server Linux/UNIX machine?  OR is the destination/ remote/ server machine also Windows?  ...I'm a bit confused because:  (1) `.hushlogin` is only detected&acted-upon on the *server* side -- so having that file on your windows machine won't have any effect.  And (2) MOTD is a *NIX server-side thing, not a normal part of Windows.

Comment: Also:  (a) the server side `sshd_config` file can include the option `PrintMotd yes/no` (b) when you add a remote command to run onto the end of the ssh.exe command line (like `ls`), nothing interactive or "login" or "shell" -related is supposed to happen (/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, /etc/bashrc) but those *might* happen anyway with $ENV or $BASH_ENV in the server side sshd configs.  -- in this case look through those files to see if they somehow invoke `motd` -- if they do, it should only be done for "interactive" shells (if `test -n "$PS1"` or `tty`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to put a file called "config" in the user's .\ssh\ folder (the same one as the id_rsa files sit in) and put the following in it:

```
LogLevel QUIET
```

Comment: You can also limit it to a single noisy host: `Host <noisy-host> LogLevel QUIET` (With a newline before `LogLevel`.)

Comment: You can also run `ssh` with `ssh -oLogLevel=QUIET` if you can't/don't want to change the configuration in `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 0):

Per the various comments above, you **should not** get MOTD if your ssh command line includes a (non-interactive) command to run on the server, for example `ls`:

```
C:\> \Git\bin\ssh.exe user@host "ls -l *.cc"
```

However, if the command above *does* give you the MOTD (as well as the output from `ls`), then something is broken or misconfigured -- probably on the server side.
But you might still be able to work around it:

- `-N`  No login shell on remote/server side
- `-T`  Force no TTY / terminal allocation on the server side

Try one or both of those flags:

```
C:\> \Git\bin\ssh.exe -N -T user@host "ls -l *.cc"
```

Comment: This question was specifically about using Git over ssh - at no point am I calling ssh directly.